# How do I set a conditional threshold for my output predictions?

Tags: python, list

I have a machine learning model which does multi-label text classification. I have a predictor object which successfully predicts the classifications of strings of text I use as input. It assigns it's prediction to single prediction as list that looks like this:

```
[('unrelated', 0.9684208035469055), ('curated', 0.02895800955593586)]
```

I feel like this could be very simple, but essentially I just need to 
create a threshold for the curated matches.

So if the confidence for curated is above .90 or something like that, I can print a statement.

However, I don't know how to specify this condition.

It's a list object, so I tried specify the index. However each index outputs both `['label', confidence]`. Moreover, the order of the index switches depending on the confidence. It always displays the highest level confidence label first. So specifying the index number wouldn't help much since it changes.

```
single_prediction = predictor.predict(result)
df.at[0,'prediction'] = single_prediction
if single_prediction[0] >= .95:
    print('this is a match')
print(single_prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using list comprehensions :

```
results = [ [('curated', 0.6), ('unrelated', 0.4)],
           [('unrelated', 0.55), ('curated', 0.45)],
          [('unrelated', 0.7), ('curated', 0.3)]]

threshold = 0.4
for result in results:
    if [x[1] for x in result if x[0] == 'curated'][0] > threshold:
        print(result)
```

---

Output :

```
[('curated', 0.6), ('unrelated', 0.4)]
[('unrelated', 0.55), ('curated', 0.45)]
```

Comment: I got an "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Comment: You get this error with your data not mine right ? If that's the case, could you post a sample of your data so I can see where my code fails on your data ?

Comment: Ok, idk why, but when I removed the result_2 and changed result_1 to result, it worked. (Which is great for my purposes, thank you so much.